# MDI window and close button

Tags: genero

whenever a modal dialog (e.g. call fgl_winmessage(...)) is open from a MDI  window the close action is disabled. I allready tried to reactived from the menu with a dialog.setActionActive with no sucess. Any ideas will be highly appreciated.
TIA
Frederico Moreira

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a simple application and testing it?

```
IMPORT FGL fgldialog

MAIN
    CALL fgl_winMessage("title","text","info")
END MAIN
```

I did this and there is no "close" action but there is an "ok" action which is enabled.  Any buttons on other forms would be disabled because the modal form has exclusive focus.  The window menu has a "Close Alt+F4" menu item and it is enabled too.

I suspect you might need to look at your action defaults or style files to see if anything is interfering there.

The `fgl_winMessage()` function has no `COMMAND close` block in the code so if a button for close did appear on the modal form then it would be disabled.